# Git autocomplete is asking for a password, not sure why

Tags: 12.10, bash, git

I'm running into an issue with autocomplete using git...
I am using ubuntu 12.10 and
when I perform the following keystrokes

<kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>

I am presented with the error

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a
>   terminal.

and prompted for a password. I am not clear how to go about troubleshooting this error, I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling git to no avail.

Screenshot of terminal with error: [image: terminal with error]

Diff between `/root/.bashrc` & `~/.bashrc`

```
3a4
> export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun"
21a23,25
> JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun"
> export JAVA_HOME
> 
51a56,63
> git_prompt()
> {
>   git_branch=$(git branch 2>/dev/null | sed -n '/^\*/s/^\* //p')
>   if [ -n "$git_branch" ]; then
>       echo "($git_branch)"
>   fi
> }
> 
53c65
<     PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
---
>     PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$(git_prompt)\$ '
55c67
<     PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
---
>     PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(git_prompt)\$ '
84a97,100
> # Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
> #   sleep 10; alert
> alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
> 
97,99c113,115
< #if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
< #    . /etc/bash_completion
< #fi
---
> if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
>     . /etc/bash_completion
> fi
```

Comment: The `Pseudo-terminal...` error is nearly always seen in the context of `ssh` (if you search Launchpad and Ubuntuforums); perhaps there is something in your environment or in your `.bashrc` like an alias, function or some variable that is causing the trouble.

Comment: After testing your setup with the files provided, I can't seem to reproduce the problem; I assume you haven't got a `.bash_aliases` file, as it's not sourced in `.bashrc`.

Comment: @Mik The `~/.bash_aliases` file was the problem I narrowed it down to the alias line `alias test="ssh username@some.server.com"`. Commenting out that line fixes the problem, thank you.

Comment: Great- I'll put it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After discussing in the comments about possible solutions to do with possibles aliases in `.bashrc` and anomalous environmental variables, we came to the conclusion that the problem lay in the `.bash_aliases` file, which contained the line:

```
alias test="ssh username@some.server.com"
```

This was logical, as I tested the `.bashrc` provided and it worked perfectly without the error occuring, so the problem had to lay in another file.

This confirmed my initial suspicion that the issue was something to do with `ssh`, as the error:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal
```

only occurs when `ssh` is concerned, as noted [here at Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-958725.html) and [here at Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114990/pseudo-terminal-will-not-be-allocated-because-stdin-is-not-a-terminal). Therefore it seemed that there was no bug in bash autocomplete or git, and so the problem was discovered.

Comment: any idea why git tab completion runs `test`?

Comment: @Soldier.moth I'm not sure- it's an interesting one; I'll see if I can find out.

Comment: in the version of git that came with ubuntu 11.04(1.7.4.1) there wasn't any use of `test` in the [auto completion script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.7.4.1/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash) but in the git that comes with ubuntu 12.10(1.7.10.4) it does [1.7.4.1 auto completion script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.7.10.4/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash)

Comment: @Soldier.moth I see now, that's useful to remember.